# How to expose many Angular 2 components from a library --> missing CommonModule

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, angular-cli-v6

My goal is to make Angular libraries in separated Angular Workspaces / code repositories to serve external Angular projects.
I want to organize this properly as the ecosystem will last for long and scale.

So far, I have been able to expose components by exporting their hosting module and use their tag from templates in the front projects.
Now I need to use some of these components directly from the routing, then I need to import each of these components explicitly in the module/routing class.

To do so, I need to export the components from the library and that's where I am struggling. When I try to export them from the module class, I have no error but they don't get publicly exposed as types (but I can use their tags from templates when the lib module is imported). The only Types being exposed are:

- [LibName]Component
- [LibName]Service
- [LibName]Module

Which are exported from the file "public_api.ts" in my lib project.

```
export * from './lib/my-lib.service';
export * from './lib/my-lib.component';
export * from './lib/my-lib.module';
```

Ok, then I thought that adding exports to that file for the missing components would do the trick, but it didn't. I get this error on build

```
Cannot determine the module for class MyComponent in [path]! Add MyComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
```

Knowing that the components are in the module 
declarations and exports:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ ],
    declarations: [ [ProjectName]Component, MyFirstComponent, MySecondComponent],
    exports: [ [ProjectName]Component, MyFirstComponent, MySecondComponent ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution while writing the question.. huh..

So I'm posting in case it helps someone.

I was just missing the CommonModule import in my module definition:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

and

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule ], // <-- add this
    declarations: [ [ProjectName]Component, MyFirstComponent, MySecondComponent],
    exports: [ [ProjectName]Component, MyFirstComponent, MySecondComponent ],
})
```

Node that I created the library using Angular CLI 6 as follows:

```
ng generate library my-library --prefix ml
```

In the result, the CommonModule was not imported in the module definition. I would have expected the statements as a library is supposed to host more than the root classes.